# Conversion of Object to another type of Object using TypeConverter in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, typeconverter

I am trying my best to understand the use of TypeConverters and how to use them.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Globalization

<TypeConverter(GetType(OrderTypeConverter))>
Public Class OrderType1

Public Sub New()

Public Sub New(Order As OrderType2)
    OrderNumber = Order.OrderNo
    'Etc Etc
End Sub

Public Property OrderNumber As String
Public Property OrderDescription As String

End Class

Public Class OrderType2

Public Property OrderNo As String
Public Property Description As String

End Class

Public Class OrderTypeConverter
Inherits TypeConverter

Public Overrides Function CanConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, destinationType As Type) As Boolean
    If destinationType = GetType(OrderType2) Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return MyBase.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType)
End Function

Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, culture As CultureInfo, value As Object, destinationType As Type) As Object

    If destinationType = GetType(OrderType2) Then

        Dim OldOrder As OrderType1 = DirectCast(value, OrderType1)

        Dim NewOrder As New OrderType2
        NewOrder.Description = OldOrder.OrderDescription
        NewOrder.OrderNo = OldOrder.OrderNumber

        Return NewOrder
    End If

    Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
End Function

End Class
```

I am not sure how to implement the conversion if the above is correct.

I know the alternative would be to pass an Order of OrderType2 into a new method of an Order Of OrderType1 and then go through all the properties etc etc but there has to be a better way

Comment: Your TypeConverter is copying property values one by one anyway so what does it save?  There doesnt seem to be anything different in those 2 types.  I suspect Inheritance might play a role in whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I am not in control of OrderType2 and the class cannot inherited.

I am trying to go with best practice for a learning experience and not fudging it.